# How to display arabic characters in forms 6i?

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, oracleforms

We have a very old application developed in Developer 2000 (Forms 6i), the Arabic characters are displayed as junk characters on the form fields.
The database is 11g and the data is available in Arabic characters, so no issue in the NLS settings of the database.
The only issue is to display the characters on the forms in proper Arabic (we don't have the source code for the forms).

The NLS_LANG settings in the registry are `american_america.ar8mswin1256`, we changed it to `ARABIC_SAUDI ARABIA.AR8MSWIN1256` and `ARABIC_United Arab Emirates.AR8MSWIN1256` but it doesn't work.

The developers are not reachable and I remember they told about `UIFONT.ALI` file, we tried everything but still no luck.

We believe it has something to do with the interface font.

If anyone has any idea on how to display Arabic properly on the forms, please help.

Thanks.